# What is the best way to respond to an incorrect answer when a comment is not enough?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, answers-in-comments

I just had an answer to the question [What can someone do while forced to doff armor from the heat metal spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53469/what-can-someone-do-while-forced-to-doff-armor-from-the-heat-metal-spell) removed, with the suggestion that it might be better as a comment.

I initially started writing the response as a comment on an answer that had a significantly incorrect part to it. However a comment was not long or detailed enough to have made it clear what I meant. The response appeared to be a partial answer even though in a "negative" manner (as in the opposite sense, not in the "this is rubbish" sense: it is a good question).

It seems cumbersome to ask another question and answer it myself, and then to refer to that from a comment, but this appears to be the only way of providing a detailed response to an answer with an issue in it other than writing a full answer.

What is the preferred way to respond to an incorrect answer when a comment is not long or detailed enough and your response is not perceived to be a full and/or direct answer to the question?

Comment: In this specific case, that exact question was asked [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/86309/15469), which was itself marked as a duplicate of [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60586/15469).

Comment: It's also worth noting, calling that answer incorrect is a bit of a stretch, really. It lists 3 options, only one of which you're objecting to. And even then, it specifically says that option is debatable and up to the GM.

Comment: [Related] [Should I be requesting people answer the question independently?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3326)

Answer (score 19):

Downvote it. Leave a concise comment. If I can, write a better answer.

Downvote because I find the answer unhelpful: this gives the writer a signal that there's something wrong, and more importantly it helps the site sort answers by quality so future readers can tell the answer's got something fishy going on.

Leave a comment saying "I think X is wrong" without explaining it. Give the answerer some credit and just point them in the right direction as much as I can in a single comment.

Write a better answer because we need good answers. In the long run, it's more important that a good answer be provided than that a bad answer be fixed. It's always nice to help improve answers, but that's just another path to the same result of "providing good answers." (If an answer is flat-out wrong, or irrelephant, what good will a comment do? There's not something to fix, the whole post is fundamentally flawed.)

If I can't figure out how to help improve it AND I can't write a better answer myself, that's okay. Downvote and move on, trusting if the writer can't figure it out on their own from the downvote then somebody else will probably help where I couldn't. That's the power of crowd-sourcing.

And let it go. It's okay for [someone to be wrong on the Internet](https://xkcd.com/386/); I'm not the only person who will feel the need to correct them, if indeed they need correcting at all. Again, it's more important that there be a good answer than that the bad answers get told why they're bad.

Comment: Comment made. Thank you BESW.