# Change the question featured in the Tour

Tags: support, tour

Our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) currently features [Are Hags Fey or Fiends?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/92374/are-hags-fey-or-fiends). One of the answers featured begins with "To add to Dressy's answer ..." which might not be setting the best example of what kind of answers we expect per [Should I be requesting people answer the question independently?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently).

If this is configurable and not just random from time to time, could it be set to a different question?

(I don't have a specific suggestion for *which* question right now.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What we should probably do is deal with the answer post's content issue, either by deleting it, editing it to be minimally complete, or converting it to a comment.

Aside, this is a *great* example of why answers need to be complete answers on their own — they won't always be shown with other posts the way the answer-writer sees them.

Comment: I've edited the answer in question to be minimally complete and not phrased like a response. It's still not a *great* answer, but it at least doesn't read like a forum post any more.

Comment: @ObliviousSage Thank you! (Interestingly I'm still seeing the original version in the tour, but I expect that's just caching and it will catch up soon enough.)

Comment: And now it's up-to-date. Caching!

Comment: Mods *should* have the tools to [select example questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163947/what-determines-the-questions-available-for-selection-in-the-tour-page), unless something has changed in the last month or two (based on [this recent MSO discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341824/question-example-in-the-tour-is-misleading)).

Comment: @TuggyNE Aha! Yes, there are discreet edit buttons on the tour in Mod-O-Vision. … The selection of questions available to choose from aren't the best though — looks like the selecting algorithm prioritises attention paid to the question rather than quality, which mostly means old or problematic questions, so we've got some … less than representative options for the example. Now it's fixed, the hag one is pretty decent actually.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I agree, it's pretty decent now! The question featured in the tour has been very effectively changed -- just not in the sense I originally suggested. ;)