# Should every answer be "The Answer"?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes a person doesn't have "***The Exact Perfect Answer***" but tries to help with some suggestions or a bit of brainstorming.  After all, there are multiple playstyles, but frequently I see those "secondary answers" being down voted.  Which of those behaviors would be considered appropriate?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a mixture of things you might be referring to. I'll go through our policy:

- We expect that answers should be an attempt to wholly and independently answer the question, such that it could work if no other answer existed. We don't do "tack-on" answers, though you might see those on other stacks. ([Should I be requesting people answer the question independently?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/should-i-be-requesting-people-answer-the-question-independently))

  - We also expect people to never answer in comments. You can suggest an improvement to an existing answer, but comments that are not suggestions and are wholly attempts to answer the question are deleted on sight. ([Should users refrain from answers (or partial answers) in comments?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments))
- You mention "help with some suggestions or a bit of brainstorming": we expect homebrew to be backed up *by actual experience*, either yours or someone's you can cite. Anyone can just come up with homebrew from their armchair without ever trying it, but we're looking for *solutions that actually work.* ([Is homebrew an acceptable answer to a question?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-homebrew-an-acceptable-answer-to-a-question))

You don't need to have an exact perfect answer, but we have quality expectations. The short summary is answer the question directly, and cite and back up your answer with facts/experience. We don't want armchair speculation, anyone can do it, we're fine without it.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what i was looking for, sometimes a "try this, it can be fun" question may look healthy but if you think about it, anyone can do it, the person questioning probably did it but is asking for more precise answers.

Comment: @MoonKnight98 Yeah, that's exactly it. Anyone at all can come up with arbitrary ideas, people are great at that. It's another thing entirely if we know they work reasonably well and understand *how* they work in practice such that we can judge whether or not we should be using them. We're trying to build up a useful public resource, and that requires collecting the tried-and-tested solutions, not the untested ones someone just came up with on the spot.